# Getting Unauthorized error when trying to execute the RestSharp request that retrieves data from ArangoDB

Tags: api, arangodb

If I send the http request through Postman it works and I get the result. But the same is not working and getting Unauthorized when I execute through RestSharp.

Below is the code snippet:

```
var client = new RestClient(
   "http://Username:Password@localhost:port/_db/databaseName/_api/simple/all");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", 
     "{\n    \"collection\":\"collectionName\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
return response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the restsharp wiki](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Authenticators) you cannot specify the authentication parameters via the URL:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("username", "foo", "password", "bar");
var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
client.Execute(request);
```

in general its a good idea in such a case to drop https, and use [wireshark](https://wireshark.org) or [ngrep](http://ngrep.sourceforge.net/) to inspect whats going on on the wire:

```
GET /_db/_system/_api/version?details=true HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: ArangoDB
Accept-Encoding: deflate
Authrization: Basic cm9vdDo=
```

to inspect the actualy generated authentication headers.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But instead of SimpleAuthenticator (still got Unauthorized ) I used HttpBasicAuthenticator and got the correct response.  client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username","password").Other option I tried is adding header. request.AddHeader("Authorization","Basic " + "username:password in base64encoded format e.g. Zm9vOmJhcg==");

Answer (score 0):

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("admin","admin");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
client.Execute(request);
```

This works for me..